# How should/could/must I handle the dll that my C++ projects depend on?

Tags: c++, dll, nuget

I'm lost here and I have no clue how to proceed. This is not a question about how to make my program work, this is a question about how to stop wasting my time.

My programming environment is Visual Studio 2013 on windows, in C++.

I use 3 libraries extensively, namely: boost (using dynamic linking), OpenCV, and Qt.

During the development, I have configured VS to look at those 3 libraries by default for include and .lib. I have also added the 3 folders containing all the dlls to my PATH environment variable.

It works, but it is sometime painful, let me explain you when.

- First hassle: Anytime I have a LNK error telling me I miss a function, it is usually on OpenCV since it has only one include file referencing all the functions. I have to look at OpenCV's source code to see what module this function belongs to and to know what I must link my program to.
- Second Hassle: When comes the time to deploy my application, I have to ship it with all the relevant dlls. To know which one I need, I open dependency walker and try to forget nothing, I have then to test it on a different computer because 102% of the time I have missed a couple, and then I have to configure my Installer generator to include all those one by one.
- Third Hassle: To ease a little bit the process of configuring a new development machine, I have recently switched to NuGet. It is great, I add boost with a couple of clicks to any project. But now my boost DLLs are *everywhere*, I have one folder per boost library, and since there are dozens of those I can't even add them all at once to my PATH now, so I have to move them manually to the appropriate folder, and that is really not what I want to do with my not-so-precious-but-who-are-you-to-judge time

I have looked around and couldn't find any good practice regarding this issue, maybe because they are too obvious, or too specific to a particular setup.

How do *you* do? How would you do if you were *me*?

Answer (score 2):

We put all our external dependencies in version control along with the code.  This ensures that all code can build "out of the box" on any of our development machines and also ensures that for any given version of the code, we know exactly which dependencies is has.

The best way to check for missing dependencies is how have a good automated test suite,  if you've got comprehensive converge then if your tests pass you must have deployed the required libraries.

In terms of linking to the appropriate libraries, unfortunately, that just sounds like an issue with the structure of OpenCV (I'm not familiar with OpenCV). I tend to use dumpbin under Windows and nm under Linux to easily grep for symbols when I get link errors with an unfamiliar library.